# Saving a pointer vs passing value as const

Tags: c++

This is something from the theory of c++ which I never quite got.

I have very large list of small structures (in size) called nodes inside Class A.
So I have:

```
private:
   QList<Node> nodes;
```

Now Class A has instance of Class B (called cB) and for one of its functions it requires to iterate over nodes and just read them (it will not modify the information in any way).

```
function ClassB::readNodes(){
   for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++){
       // READ nodes and do stuff with that information
   }
}
```

So as far as I know there two ways to approach this. This is my current approach Inside Class B I have:

```
public:
    void setNodes(const QList *list) {nodes = list;}
private:
    QList<Node> *nodes;
```

And then somewhere in Class A I do:

```
cb.setNodes(&nodes);
```

The objective of this approach is that I want to avoid copying a very large data structure each time `readNodes()` is called, and also there is only one copy of the data structure in memory. This is important because Class A will continually change nodes.

The second approach is much simpler and more clear in my opinion. Simply define `readNodes` as:

```
function ClassB::readNodes(const QList<Node> &nodes){
   for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++){
       // READ nodes and do stuff with that information
   }
}
```

But I'm not totally sure that this will insume a performance penalty. As far as I understand it this approach also treats nodes as a reference and so no deep copy of nodes occurs. Is this correct?

Comment: Why a reference should be a performance problem. Internally a reference is simply a pointer. And the design sounds very broken. A class contains data and also objects which handle the data and have access to their parent class data? Maybe I have misunderstood something... In addition I dislike QAnyThing for functionality which is already given by STL. QContainers have no benefit over STL Containers as I know...

Comment: Reference or pointer doesn't matter, no copy is made. And even if you make a copy it doesn't matter because Qt used [copy on write](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html) so this is a complete non-issue.

Comment: pointer is just some integer value of memory offset, you do not copy any data when you pass it somewhere until you explicitly do it

Comment: @nwp This means that as long as I just read a class there will never be a deep copy. Correct?

Comment: Maybe I completely misunderstand the question, but why do you make a copy in the first place? Simply use only the list in `ClassB`, no need to pass the list around when anyhow the list is a member of `ClassB` and `ClassA` has a `ClassB` member

Comment: @tobi303 The list is really required for Class A which continually reads it and modifies it. However one part of the processing (which is generating the output) needs to be handled by another class so just for that one function I need to pass it to Class B. I think I've said as much in my question

Comment: @aarelovich still dont understand why you think you need to copy it. If you want to access it in `ClassA` just do it via `cB.nodes`

Comment: Yes, I guess this could be an option. But I like keeping my structures private and the structures is mainly used in class A. It is actually it's main data structure. Everything around it is is constructed to use nodes. It feels wrong to write it as a member of Class B.

Comment: hmmm I have a strong opinion against encapsulation for the sake of encapsulation. If `ClassA` needs access to `ClassB`s nodes, then why forbid that access? You could of course provide a getter (this would bring you back to the original question) or make the two classes friends if you really want to keep it private

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the Qt classes(including container classes) are [implicitly shared](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html). So even if you pass them around by value, there won't be a deep copy until you access to those items. 
Passing const references of objects is a more general and safe approach though.

Comment: So, just to be clear, you are suggesting the second option. Right?

Comment: @aarelovich: NO! The answer tells you that you can give the object, not the reference and you will still profit by copy on write. If you give a reference never any (deep ) copy is required, because a reference is technically a pointer. So please read carefully! This answer was already given in the comments to your question! So please understand what a reference is!

Comment: @aarelovich Second option saves you from copying anything more than the size of a pointer

Comment: Ok. Yes. This is what I thought but I wanted to make sure that I understood. I didn't know about the implicit sharing/copy-on-write. Thanks!

Comment: @aarelovich: You still did not understand that you have to use a reference and when doing so you have no copy and sharing problem. Again: Please understand what a reference is!

Comment: @Klaus. What you are trying to tell me is exacly the reason why I asked this question on the first place. When someone speaks of reference I automatically think of pointer. So if I don't see a explicit pointer ( somethign with a *  somewhere) I always had this doubt that somehow a deep copy was being made. The answers here made it clear that when a) When I pass somrthing like in the way of option B this never happens. And b) Qt uses copy on write so unless I try to change the structure it is never deep copied. I'm sorry but you just weren't clear to me.